# Device can't support development

Tags: ipad, provisioning, xcode-organizer

My iDevice is connected to my computer and I've been testing my app builds on it. It's been working perfectly until just recently. I went onto my iPad and deleted a provisioning profile that wasn't being used and was generating warnings in Organizer. At this point, I decide to restart my device (reasons not related to development) and when the device finishes rebooting and is connected **Organizer** shows this message:

[image: Could not support development error message]

What does that "**Could not support development**" mean?
Do I need to restore my device?

I also tried this thinking that it had somehow disconnected:

[image: Add device to provisioning portal]

At this point, Organizer asks for my login information (with my dev Apple ID and password) and tells me (after 5-6 tries) that my password and login weren't correct even though I can go online and login with those exact credentials.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Restart the phone, and Xcode, then reconnect your device and make sure you press the "Use For Development" button in the organizer.  If the doesn't work, try removing then adding your device back.

Comment: That works, but it was just so random, and I can't stand "random" (or seemingly random) errors.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect! Restart iDevice and XCode.

If this not work, try to reset devices on developer.apple.com